# What must truly be done to share a folder and access it on another PC

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, shared-folders

I'm creating a chat program that uses LAN and shared folders in Windows 10. However, I'm having trouble with sharing the folders and seeing them on other computers. I'm wondering what needs to be set in

1. Network and Sharing Center
2. The Sharing tab on the folder
3. The Security tab on the folder
4. Firewall Settings
5. Any other settings that might block it.

I need to know what settings I need for the host and for the one viewing the folder especially.

I will be writing a script that automates all the settings in Batch, however I can do that myself if I know what needs to be set. I know this is a big question but I wish to point out that I am **not** asking anyone to write a script for me.

Edit: I already have a working LAN and workgroup

Comment: is it to be assumed you already have a functional lan and workgroup upon which to add shares?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The workgroup is set to default.

Comment: Are all the devices on the same workgroup, IP subnet, and Ethernet LAN (same broadcast/multicast domain)? Because it gets tricky fast when you need to cross routers to reach other LANs and subnets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For workgroup sharing to a LAN, all that is generally required is:

- A user account or set of user accounts that exist on both PCs. for seamless access the usernames and passwords for each account should be the same on all machines.
- A directory with permissions such that it is accessible to the users who will be able to access the share (in the security tab). Set the permissions to reflect what you want the user to be able to actually do, so make them tight.
- Share configured to allow "Everyone: full control". Don't worry that you are providing too much privilege (that they are too loose). Share permissions cannot override hard disk permissions, so [most recommend](https://blog.foldersecurityviewer.com/best-practice-ntfs-share-permissions/) putting all your permissions logic on the directories, rather than the share. That is because you have to do twice the work to configure access at the directory **and** the share, and because disk permissions are written to the filesystem, but share permissions are in the registry, so if your OS is damaged and you have to rebuild the OS, the permissions logic for shares from non-OS disks would be lost. The only reason you would want to do otherwise is if a local user needed access to a directory, but should only be able to access it locally.
- [A common version of the SMB (and NTLM) protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#History) between network nodes. This is not generally a problem unless you are trying to connect to/from a very old version of windows, from a very new version.

Almost all windows firewalls will automatically allow network sharing, but if you were to configure it manually you would need to [open the following ports to the LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#Features):

- UDP\137
- UDP\138
- TCP\139
- TCP\445